# Initialising AKAudioFile gives malloc error

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, audiokit

I'm recording an audio file successfully and adding filter to it. This is done using AudioKit framework

The following code is about playing the filtered audio

```
                let audioFilename = self.getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent(self.storedFileToPlay!)
                var audioFile : AKAudioFile? = nil
                do {

                    if (audioFile == nil)
                    {
                        audioFile = try AKAudioFile.init(forReading: audioFilename)
                    }


                }catch{
                    print (error)
                }
              guard audioFile != nil else {return}
                if (player == nil)
                {
                    player = try AKAudioPlayer(file: audioFile!)
                }
                else
                {
                    try player?.replace(file: audioFile!)
                }

                player?.looping = false

                let timePitch = AKTimePitch(player)
                timePitch.pitch = 800.0


                AudioKit.output = timePitch

                AudioKit.start()

                player?.play()

                player?.completionHandler = {

                    self.player?.stop()
                    audioFile = nil
                    self.player = nil

                }
```

This works properly for 1 time, but the 2nd time this function gets called I get malloc: *** error for object 0x14db7a60: pointer being freed was not allocated error just in the point where the audioFile is being initialised.

I kept looking into it but was in vain.

Funny thing, if I use a static m4a file in the bundle, it'll keep on playing over and over and over with no crash.

Also the crash weirdly occurs in the device but not in the simulator, which is irritating.

Where is this issue getting caused?

Comment: What did you use instead of "a static m4a file in the bundle"? On which line exactly does the malloc occur?